# Which free library should I use to perform cutting/clipping operation?

Tags: computational-geometry, software

I have a set of points which forms a closed loop, and I want to perform cutting/clipping a 3D model using this loop. I have used VTK but in some cases, it has a "Cannot follow edges" problem.

Is there any free library I can use to do such operation?

Comment: What is the representation of your 3D model? Is it a mesh, BRep, NURBS, …?

Comment: It is a mesh which is stored in th STL format

Comment: The statement of your requirements is unclear; a 3D volume can be cut by defining a surface, not a curve.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit suspicious that VTK (and supposedly Paraview) has troubles with your mesh: there is a slight chance that there are some troubles with it.

One solution would be to try using [GMSH](http://gmsh.info/). It supports STL input and certainly has clipping capability. Now, with the newest versions, it also supports access to its functionality via API for at least C/C++/Python.